# Get specific text from text field in formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field

i have 1 text field. the field format will be **"Target XXXXX X"**. the question is , how can i get the **"XXXXX X"** value from my text field to my formula ( text) field.

Example 1 : "Target Kindergarten 1" -> "Kindergarten 1" (formula field)
Example 2 : "Target Grade 1" -> "Grade 1" (formula field)

i try using `RIGHT(field__c,FIND(" ",field__c))` in my formula but it only read the first space from the right and outcome will be "1".
How can i get the second space from left so the output will be "Kindergarten 1"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take help from `SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text, new_text)` function . for example

TRIM( SUBSTITUTE(Target Kindergarten 1, Target, ''));
it will give you

> Kindergarten 1
>   This code will only work if you have fixed text value **Target**.

Comment: Hi @Tushar, if i use SUBTITUTE function. it will be fixed text right ? the whole text value must be "Target Kindergarten 1" or only "Target" must be fixed

Comment: you can bind your field here